# Acessar memória alocada em um ponteiro

Tags: c, alocação, array

Se eu tiver um vetor de ponteiros do tipo `*p[tamanho]`, no qual cada posição será ocupada por `p[tamanho] = malloc(10*sizeof(int))`, como fazer para acessar cada posição desse vetor alocado com o `malloc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que tal assim?

```c
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        printf("%d ", p[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Observe que no primeiro par de colchetes, acessamos uma posição do array, o que resulta em um ponteiro. Com o segundo par de colchetes, acessamos a posição do array a partir do ponteiro resultante.